# Dynamic controllers based on route's model in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

So, I'm looking for some help getting my Ember routes to dynamically setup the controller/template based on a property from the model. Basically I'm loading up an STI-based model from Rails and then I'd like to mimic what STI does by utilizing controllers and templates to handle the different functionality of different types of a model (the structure of the data is the same for all types).

I've tried an `afterModel` hook, passing in a computed property to the `controllerName` property of the model, and just about everything I can think of in between.  Here's an example of what I'm attempting to do (the browser just freezes when I do this):

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend
  type: DS.attr('string') # Can be 'MultipleChoiceQuestion' or 'ShortAnswerQuestion'
  text: DS.attr('string')

App.MultipleChoiceQuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()

App.ShortAnswerQuestionController = Ember.Object.Controller.extend()

App.QuestionRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> store.find 'question', params.question_id
  afterModel: (question, transition) ->
    type = question.get('type')
    @set('controllerName', type)
```

I've also tried variations of the following:

```
App.QuestionRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> store.find 'question', params.question_id
  controllerName: Em.computed 'currentModel', ->
    @currentModel.get('type')
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment on the best way to do this!

Comment: as per naming convention or question route should be named `QuestionRoute` as opposed to `QuestionRouter`. Was that a typo?

Comment: Thanks, for the catch - just a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I changed, but after much `console.log`ing I got the `afterModel` hook to set the `controllerName` property.  I was able to use a similar method in the `renderTemplate` hook to dynamically set my template based on the model's `type` property...